# python time.time() in future after one year

Tags: python

In my application, I have to store timestamp of current time and same time in future after 1 year.

To get current time, I'm using

```
import time
ct = int(time.time())
```

**How to time at present in future after 1 year?**

Comment: Define "1 year". Is `ct + 60*60*24*365` accurate enough?

Comment: Is it 365 days hence? Same day of same month next year (February 29ths are tricky...)? Does the weekday matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.utcnow()
future = now + timedelta(days=365)

now_timestamp = int(now.timestamp())
future_timestamp = int(future.timestamp())
```

If you have to consider leap years, I would recommend using the [`Pendulum`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) library.